# How to suppress Turbolinks response when using JQuery form submit with Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

Given a form that is being submitted with JQuery in CoffeeScript:

```
$('form').submit ->
    $.ajax
      url: $('form').attr('action')
      type: 'POST'
      data: $('form').serialize()
      success: (data, status, xhr) ->
        ...
    false
```

The form submits with

```
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
```

The form submits as expected and the controller action calls `redirect_to` .

The response is 200 with body:

```
Turbolinks ClearCache...
Turbolinks.visit...
```

The success handler is never called, probably because Turbolinks intercepts the response.

So, how to suppress the TurboLinks response from the Rails app?

```
turbolinks (5.1.1)
turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
rails (4.2.10)
```

I tried adding `data-turbolinks: 'false'` to the form, but that did not do anything.

Comment: Did you want to remove turbolinks from your application or just in this one case?

Comment: are you sure responding back as json ? Since you are able to submit, it's not gonna be an issue to accept response...

Comment: @KieranAndrews - Just one page (or form).

Comment: @BSeven Can you please include controller code?

Comment: `The success handler is never called, probably because Turbolinks intercepts the response.` how do you know this is the case?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon - `console.log(...)` in the success handler does not run. Also, I saw a SO question with the same symptom.

Comment: @Rthi - The relevant part of the controller code is `redirect_to`.

Comment: @BSeven i dnt know, why dnt u post yr controller also ?

Comment: @7urkm3n - It doesn't have any information relevant to the question.

Comment: @BSeven another possible idea: have to tried adding remote: true to your form? Then you could redirect via the event handler.

Comment: You might need a `.done` and `.fail`. 

`$.ajax(
  method: 'POST'
  url: $('form').attr('action')
  data: $('form').serialize()
).done((data) ->
  alert 'Data: ' + data
  return
).fail (jqXHR, textStatus) ->
  alert 'Request failed: ' + textStatus
  return`

Comment: @GundamMeister - I thought `success` has replaced `done`...?

Comment: according to `http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/` , `.done` is being used.

Comment: OK I see it says `Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.`